# Output impedance of a differential line receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, impedance, output, receiver

Let's say I have an INA134 (http://www.ti.com/product/ina134) from Texas Instruments in my design. I want to take the output of that IC and feed it into a resistor network which can have a flexible input resistance (from 100 ohm to 100k ohm).

What is the reason that the output impedance of the IC is not specified in the datasheet? It's based on a simple opamp circuit after all.

Does it make sense to follow the INA134 by a OPA134 to allow for more drive capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output drive capability is defined in a few places in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina134.pdf), but not guaranteed except at 2K load. The below graph is based on +/-18V supplies.

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina134.pdf]

As you can see you can get 20mA easily out of it, with 15V swing. With a 100R load, the output capability would be a couple of volts or so safely.

I don't see why you'd want to follow this part with another such as the [OPA134](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa134.pdf) that has similar or less current capability.

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa134.pdf]

Keep in mind that the *closed-loop output impedance* on both amplifiers will appear very low, up until the point where you hit the current limit (or when thermal protection kicks in).

Comment: I know that the OPA134 has a pretty small output impedance so I thought I'd use that as a voltage follower.
My main question here is: How do I deduce the output impedance from the datasheet of the INA134?

Comment: You can't really. The typical error with a 2K load is 0.02%, so the closed-loop impedance should be < 0.4 ohm, but that error includes resistor tolerance. Close enough for audio work, in most cases.